# Reference Request: Lie Theory For Quantum Field Theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-field-theory

I have encountered the section on non-Abelian gauge theories in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT textbook, and although I am comfortable with the derivation of the Yang-Mills Lagrangian they present, the discussion that follows on Lie groups / algebras and their representation I am struggling with.

The relevant section of the book seems to be written as a review of the material for people already familiar with it, rather than a first introduction, so I am struggling to understand the justification for statements they make offhand.

I would appreciate it if anybody could point me towards an alternative source for this material presented in reasonable detail at a relatively elementary level. What P&S tries to cover in the space of eight pages amounts to the basics of the representation of compact Lie algebras (irreducible, conjugate, fundamental and adjoint representations), products of representations, and Casimir operators, to give a feel for the material I would like to learn before proceeding in P&S.

Comment: I've heard this book of Hall's is good. It looks very elementary and my feeling is that it's probably aimed at physicists. http://www3.nd.edu/~bhall/book/lie.htm

Comment: [**Lie Groups for Physicists**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0805339515) by Robert Hermann (1966) is a bit old but might be worth looking at. I don't know much about this topic, but I do know that Hermann's book was at least somewhat widely known in the 1970s, at least among the people I knew at the time (such as [this person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bryant_(mathematician)), who I recall saying something to the effect that he found Hermann's various books marginally inspirational).